# T-SQL: Query a Json column for records where an array element is missing a value

Tags: json, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In SQL Server 2016, I have a `Shipments` table like this:

```
create table Shipments 
(
    shipment_number varchar(20),
    shipment_json nvarchar(MAX)
);
```

`shipment_json` column contents is like this:

```
{
    "shipmentNumber": "008863",
    "stops": [
        {
            "locations": [
                {
                    "stopRole": "originPort",
                    "closeDateTime": "2023-08-22T05:00:00"
                },
                {
                    "stopRole": "destinationPort"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I please need a `SELECT` query for records where, in the "locations" array, the "location" element with stopRole = “destinationPort” is *missing* the closeDateTime value. The json sample above is an example of that.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: The point where you have to start breaking open JSON data to check individual values inside to use in places like WHERE or ON predicates is the point where you should also be thinking about updating the application and database to have this information as part of the base schema, and extract it only at INSERT/UPDATE time. Sure, the JSON extraction works, but it's not exaggeration or hyperbole to say building it into the schema is **multiple orders of magnitude** faster.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that is a good idea. Will have it at hand for future requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [openjson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) through [cross apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/select-selecting-from-cross-apply-and-outer-apply) enables treating the stopRole & closeDateTime as if they are typical columns e.g:

```
SELECT
      shipment_number
    , stopRole
    , closeDateTime
FROM Shipments
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(shipment_json, '$.stops')
    WITH (
        locations nvarchar(MAX) '$.locations' AS JSON
    ) AS Stops
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(Stops.locations)
    WITH (
        stopRole nvarchar(50) '$.stopRole',
        closeDateTime nvarchar(50) '$.closeDateTime'
    ) AS Locations
WHERE Locations.closeDateTime IS NULL
```

| shipment_number | stopRole | closeDateTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 008863 | destinationPort | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/it7YPG0d)

Comment: Works like a charm. I appreciate it. Also, thanks to your answer I now have a better understanding of CROSS APPLY and OPENJSON, I'm sure I'll put this knowledge to good use in the future.

Comment: Yes, it's super convenient that an alias formed in one cross apply can be used in subsequent cross applys. Nb you can also use outer apply if  it's necessary but it wasn't in this example.